# Find a XML tag inside log file using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

```
<ns2:createOrder>
         <ns2:serviceResponseContext >
            <interactionId></interactionId>
            <requestId>5</requestId>
            <requestReceivedTimestamp>Mon Jul 15 10:06:45 MDT 
</requestReceivedTimestamp>
            <responseGeneratedTimestamp>Mon Jul 15 10:07:29 MDT </responseGeneratedTimestamp>
            <serverHostPort></serverHostPort>
            <serviceDuration>44541</serviceDuration>
            <statusCode>0</statusCode>
         </ns2:serviceResponseContext>
         <ns2:createOrderResponse>
            <ns2:statusLog>
               <ns2:createOrderStep>PROVISION_CODE</ns2:createOrderStep>
               <ns2:statusCode>0</ns2:statusCode>
               <ns2:message></ns2:message>
            </ns2:statusLog>
            <ns2:statusLog>
               <ns2:createOrderStep>VISION_CODE</ns2:createOrderStep>
               <ns2:statusCode>0</ns2:statusCode>
               <ns2:message></ns2:message>
            </ns2:statusLog>
```

I need to extract the first `<statusCode>`from the XML file only when the statusCode=0 
the `<statusCode>` should be inside the `<createOrder>` using regular Expressions.

I just need the first `<statusCode>0<statusCode>` and ignore the others inside the `<createOrderStep>`

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Why would you not use an XML API instead? It's likely to be a lot less brittle...

Comment: Do not use regexes. use a proper DOM parser. You'll find it's a LOT easier doign this with xpath than it'd ever be with a regex.

Comment: Its part of my internship and I am required to use regex. Thanks for your input

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to extract `<statusCode>0</statusCode>` only when the status code number is equal to zero? If the number can't vary why bother extracting it at all? You already know exactly what you are going to get, i.e. `"<statusCode>0</statusCode>"`?

Comment: @TannyVarma recommend them to use an xml parser..revert them back here if they disagree..Also what language/tool are you using..regex implementation differs across languages/tools

Comment: Part of your internship? If your supervisors don't get why using regex to parse XML is a bad idea then run away as fast as you can - they are leading you down the path to hell!

Comment: @TannyVarma I would say that the only reason to have someone else use regular expressions to pull data out of XML is to act as a teaching moment, i.e. the student tries and fails, then the instructor comes along and says "OK, that's bad and wrong, don't do that"... the problem with this approach is that for simple cases, it will appear to do the right thing in a manner that's easy to implement, and will therefore lead the student down the primrose path. It works as well as using a screw and a hammer... you have to pound real hard, and the results won't hold up under stress.

Comment: **What have you tried so far?** To everyone else: please don't do this kid's homework.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following this works for both

`<statusCode>0</statusCode> and  <ns2:statusCode>0</ns2:statusCode>`

`/<(ns2:)?statusCode>0<\/(ns2:)?statusCode>/`

Comment: \bcreateOrderResponse\b.*\bstatusCode>0</statusCode\b ....  Can you tell me what is wrong with the above expression

Comment: Not sure why my regx wouldn't work. I have tested it before pasting. Show me the code how you are trying it. BTW I don't see createOrderResponse in the xml so not sure why you used it in your regex.